# Changing hostname doesn't change the terminal name

Tags: bash, prompt, hostname

I had set my hostname while installing linux as "ankit". i want to change it to "ankit.centos". I tried changing hostname in `/etc/hosts`, `/etc/sysconfig/network` and `sysctl kernel.hostname=ankit.centos`.

Though the hostname is set correctly which I verified by typing `hostname` on terminal, but even after restarting the system the name on terminal is not changed it still is showing `root@ankit$`.

Any clues how do change that?

Comment: What is the result of the following commands: `hostname` & `hostname -s`

Comment: @sparticvs hostname results in "ankit.centos" while hostname -s gives "ankit"

Comment: Your hostname is correct. Your prompt is only showing the shortname. Each '.' is a domain delimiter. The system is assuming that "centos" is your TLD.  If you want to make sure you see it, change your hostname to `ankit-centos`.

Comment: You'd try to set your `PS1` to `\u@\H\$`. Using `\H` instead of `\h` shows you the full hostname instead of just the short form of it.

Comment: @RistoSalminen thanks, toss that into an answer with more detail and you have an upvote inbound.

Comment: @sparticvs I'll do that as soon as I can.

Comment: Ah, @TimothyMartin already made that as an answer before I did.

Comment: @sparticvs seems 2 steps were redundant in "/etc/hosts" there was names like localhost localhost2 etc.. i now kept 'localhost & ankit.centos' is it correct or should i revert back to previous settings? also "sysctl kernel.hostname=ankit.centos" was not reuqired. should i revert it back if so whats the default value of kernale.hostname ?

Comment: @ay89 you can revert it back if you want. it shouldn't really hurt anything to be in there.

Comment: @sparticvs actually i dont have backup i could try getting default values if required :) was just asking if these two must be the same as hostname

Comment: @ay89 it should be "ankit.centos" anyway, so leave it. It should be the same as the values you set before.  I just checked my install and its the FQDN (fully-qualified domain name).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default PS1 prompt behavior is to display the hostname up to the first '.' as noted in this excerpt from the bash man page:

> PROMPTING
>          When  executing interactively, bash displays the primary prompt PS1 when it is ready to read a command, and the secondary prompt
>          PS2 when it needs more input to complete a command.  Bash allows these prompt strings to be customized by inserting a number  of
>          backslash-escaped special characters that are decoded as follows:
>
> snip
>
> > \h     the hostname up to the first ‘.’
> >
> > \H     the hostname

You can correct this by changing how your PS1 prompt is displayed in `/etc/bashrc`

[This CentOS website](http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/CustomizeBash) details methods for customizing your bash prompt, including this:

> System-wide Configuration
>
> System-wide configuration is done in /etc/bashrc. Comment out the default settings and add your customization below:
>
> # [ "$PS1" = "\s-\v\\$ " ] && PS1="[\u@\h \w]\$ "
>
> PS1='\u@\H:\w\$ '

Comment: my bad, just realized a few seconds back.